# How to use `remotes::install_gitlab` to install from a branch?

Tags: r, gitlab, remotes

I wanted to install the `interp` package from the "spline" branch in the Gitlab repository at https://gitlab.aau.at/agebhard/interp .  When I select that branch on the web page, the URL changes to https://gitlab.aau.at/agebhard/interp/-/tree/spline .  However, using that URL in the obvious way gives an error:

```r
remotes::install_gitlab("agebhard/interp", 
                        subdir = "-/tree/spline", 
                        host = "https://gitlab.aau.at")
#> Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitLab:
#>   cannot open URL 'https://gitlab.aau.at/api/v4/projects/agebhard%2Finterp/repository/files/-%2Ftree%2Fspline%2FDESCRIPTION/raw?ref=HEAD'
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

I ended up cloning the whole repository and then using `git branch` to select the branch, and installing locally.  But surely `remotes::install_gitlab()` would offer a way to install directly from a branch?  The `install_github()` function has `ref` to select a branch or tag, but I don't see an equivalent of that argument in `install_gitlab()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use just `install_git`

```
remotes::install_git(
  url = "https://gitlab.aau.at/agebhard/interp.git",
  ref = "spline"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @danlooo's answer and some debuggging, I worked out the right way to use `install_gitlab` itself.  You just put the branch at the end of the name with an `@` sign, e.g.

```
remotes::install_gitlab("agebhard/interp@spline", 
                        host = "gitlab.aau.at")
```